# Accessing other table information

Tags: catalog, products

I have access to an array from catalog/product that contains a bunch of information.  For instance:

```
$product = mage::getSingleton('catalog/products')->load(12345);    
mage::log($product->getData()); //shows me what this model contains
```

Say I want to look up the color of my product, my problem is that color is giving me a number like 1205, instead of the actual name of the color.  Do I need to be looking into  joins of different table to access the value of 1205? Thanks in advance.

Here it is in code

```
mage::log($product->color); // prints 1205
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ask magento for attribute text, here you are asking for value. Magento generates it's attributes value differently according to their type.

In your case, try this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(12345);    
$colour = $product->getAttributeText('color');
//Mage::log($colour);
Mage::log($colour, null, 'custom_log.log'); //create new log file called custom_log.log
```

**Other method to look**

```
/**
 * get attribute collection
 */
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');
/**
 * get attribute type
 */
$attribute->getAttributeType();
/**
 * get attribute Label
 */
$attribute->getFrontendLabel();
/**
 * get attribute default value
 */
$attribute->getDefaultValue();
/**
 * check if the attribute is visible
 */
$attribute->getIsVisible();
/**
 * check if the attribute is required
 */
$attribute->getIsRequired();
/**
 * get attribute value
 */
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMyAttribute();
```

[Ref](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-attribute-name-and-value/)

Comment: This solved it! thanks! Also works when I needed to get the size as well since size was giving a 4 digit number instead of human readable like XS or S.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

Firstly, you'll want to fix a few things:

- Instead of `$product->color` use `product->getColor()`
- Instead of `mage::` use `Mage::`
- Instead of `getSingleton` use `getModel`. Singletons should be reserved for things like database connections and session objects.

### On to the answer

The reason that this isn't translating for you is that you're not accessing the attribute *text*. This is distinguished in Magento from the text label associated to that value so that we can have things like multiple translations for option values.

This usually only happens in dropdown attribute types or multiselect attribute types.

Use this to access:

```
$color = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
echo $color ->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```